# Ajax auto search in codeigniter code did not works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Controller code:

```
public function auto_search() {

    $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
    //print_r($search_data);  die();
    $query = $this->search_model->autocomplete($search_data);
    print_r($query);  die();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        echo $row->uid  ;
        echo  $row->name ;
    endforeach; 
}
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxSearch() {

        var input_data = $('#search_data').val();

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/search/auto_search",
              data: {search_data:input_data},
              success: function(data1) {
              alert(data1);

                if (data1.length > 0) {
                   $('#suggestions').show();
                   $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                   $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
                }
              }
          });
    }
</script>
```

In controller when i print the search_data that is `print_r($search_data); die();` i did not get any result. 
I think ajax call is not get  in to the controller   Please provide solution for this

Moreover, when I echo out the query in controller that is `print_r($query) ;` I did not get any result. Also autosearch is not working. Please provide solution for this.

Comment: you need to pass a `JSON` back from php, not just a plain `echo`. Create an array with the results and `echo json_encode($resultArray);` so that JQuery understands the output.

Comment: @AlexTartan   u mean   in controller ?? how  to create an array  with the results  and echo out??

Comment: Something like `$res = array(); foreach ($query->result() as $row){        $res[] = array('id'=>$row->uid, 'name'=>$row->name);}echo json_encode($res); `

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ajaxSearch function not runing.
your try

```
public function auto_search()
{

    $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
    $query = $this->search_model->autocomplete($search_data);

    if (!empty($query)) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->uid;
            echo $row->name;
        }
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function ajaxSearch() {

            var input_data = $('#search_data').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/search/auto_search",
                data: {search_data: input_data},
                success: function (data1) {
                    alert(data1);

                    if (data1.length > 0) {
                        $('#suggestions').show();
                        $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // start ajaxSearch
        ajaxSearch();
    });

</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all ur data into array and then convert it into json_encode for more referrence about encoding -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php..

here is sample code for you.

```
public function auto_search() {

    $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
    //print_r($search_data);  die();
    $query = $this->search_model->autocomplete($search_data);
    //print_r($query);  die(); <- you should replace the die.


    $myArray = [];
    foreach ($query->result() as $key => $row):
        $myArray['keyname'] = $row->uid;
        $myArray['keyname1'] = $row->name;
    endforeach;

  //data retrieves by jquery
  echo json_encode($myArray);

}
```

In you jquery.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/search/auto_search",
          data: {search_data:input_data},
          success: function(data1) {
          console.log(data1);
          console.log(data1.keyname);
          console.log(data1.keyname1);

            if (data1.length > 0) {
               $('#suggestions').show();
               $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
               $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
            }
          }
      });
```

try to look at you're browser console panel. and see the retrieved data in your function and also try to check if your ajax url is correct.